# JAVA SQL JDBC PreparedStatement Insert with Case not unique?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, insert, prepared-statement

I have a working dbconnection (JDBC, Oracle) and most request work fine, especially some Prepared Batched Statements.
I have an existing db `testdb` with **primary key** `MESSID`.

When using a statement (not prepared) `stm`, the following works fine::

```
stm.addBatch("insert into testdb (\"MESSID\",\"METAFID\",\"POSITIONSNUMMER\") select case when count(*)=0 then 1 else 1+max(messid) end,HEXTORAW(''3637534FD7ED259449DBF86E2A283890''),1 from testdb");
stm.addBatch("insert into testdb (\"MESSID\",\"METAFID\",\"POSITIONSNUMMER\") select case when count(*)=0 then 1 else 1+max(messid) end,HEXTORAW(''A17F5E246F1E44D78228C39274E226B2''),2 from testdb");
stm.addBatch();
stm.executeBatch()
```

When doing the same with preparedCalls (PreparedStatements, inserting "METAFID","POSITIONSNUMMER" with set...), those queries struggle up when doing `.executeBatch`.
I'm not sure, but thinking, the `select case when count(*)=0 then 1 else 1+max(messid)` fragment is going wrong (**java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00001: Unique Constraint (????.testdb)**).
Who can help or tell own experiences?

Comment: Can you post the not working code with the prepared statement ?

Comment: Do ***not*** use `max(id) + 1` to generate IDs. Just don't. Use a sequence instead.

Comment: @dystroy, I use those code within MATLAB - und thus it is running that way.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, what is the problem with this max(id)+1? Why are sequences better? I "feel them" a little bit more complicated.

Comment: Because you example is plain wrong (run this with two concurrent transactions and look what happens). *If* you get this transactionally correct it will most definitely be slow as hell if you have multiple transactions trying to get the next number. And why is `select nextval('your_sequence')` more complicated than `select max(id) from some_table`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - okay, thanks - I did not know that. Here is a matching (translated quote from [german wikibooks](http://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Oracle:_Sequenzen)):  
**Sense of a sequence is the avoidance of the popular beginner error "select max (id) +1 from xyz" to generate the next primary key value.**

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name please write your comment as an answer thus I can accept it. Thanks.